# How to auto increment object keys in aws S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have two aws buckets. I am using the aws-sdk and the s3.copyObject function to move objects from the first bucket to the second. In the second bucket I want the objects to have an auto-incremented key. IE: the first object in the bucket has the key '1', then '2', '3',.. etc.

How do I set incrementing keys in S3? Obviously this would need to override whatever key name is provided.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: incremented ids in keys is pretty common. I'm just wondering if there is a way to get S3 to do it for me.

Comment: That is fine, but my question is why you want to do this, there has to be some reason right?

Comment: I want to backup a subset of the S3 objects, and give them a human-readable ID, instead of the UUID it currently has.

Comment: @ChrisStPierre An object's key in S3 is analogous to a filename and not an ID column of a database table.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is not a database.  It's a (flat) filesystem.  You are expected to create object keys yourself.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html (bold mine):

> When you create an object, **you** specify the key name, which
>   uniquely identifies the object in the bucket.